# ' " turns out as \' and \"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, character-encoding

so I have a field you can type in. After you type you press ok, and it will send an ajax call to `save.php` and it inserts into the database (with php), and then output what you have type. And then ajax call on succes grabs the output and alerts it (`success: function(msg){ alert(msg) }`). the response is in html.

Works good until i use `'` or `"` in the field. example if i write: `'asdadsasd"` it turns out: `\&#039;asdadsasd\&quot;` How can I fix this?

Dont know if it matters, but in save.php I have:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And it outputs the message like this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($message), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

Comment: Misconfigured PHP, look for `magic_quotes_gpc` in your php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `ENT_QUOTES` option, I let you check: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

EDIT: I've forgotten slashes, have you magic_quotes activated?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to PHP's exceptionally <strike>helpful</strike> irritating ["magic quotes"](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) feature. Magic quotes automatically inserts slashes before single and double quotes in incoming data provided by the user agent (i.e. in `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE`, or "GPC") in a vague attempt at providing some security for those who don't realize the hazards of unescaped user input.

As a matter of course, you should *always* check for magic quotes using [`get_magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) before you attempt to use any GPC data. If it's enabled, simply call [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on your input before using it.

I use something similar to this at the beginning of any script I write:

```
function cleanInput($input)
{
    if (is_array($input))
    {
        foreach ($input as &$value)
        {
            $value = cleanInput($value);
        }

        return $input;
    }
    else
    {
        return stripslashes($input);
    }
}

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $_GET = cleanInput($_GET);
    $_POST = cleanInput($_POST);
    $_COOKIE = cleanInput($_COOKIE);
    $_REQUEST = cleanInput($_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: I tried this: $response = ( (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? stripslashes($_POST['comment']) : $_POST['comment'] ); it still gives me: &#039; &quot;&quot;

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `stripslashes` on it. I think it adds slashes when it's posted/sent via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

use **stripslashes**